# How to get alert when a radio button is not checked?

Tags: html, validation, radio-button

I have an application in which i have radio buttons. I am able to get the status of the all checked radio buttons in an alert box.Now i want to show an alert if a radio button remain unchecked saying that some error or can not left blank or something. I added my code here

http://jsfiddle.net/janakipriya/hRzZf/19/.

when i click on save button it should show an alert if any of the radio button is unchecked.Can anyone please help me how to do that.

Comment: What is the point? There will always be a button unchecked.

Comment: @MichalKlouda In every row it has an accept or reject button and it showing status of radio button of every row i mean 1. accept 2.accept 3.reject so on when there is no selection of neither accept nor reject in any of the row i should get an alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this, http://jsfiddle.net/hRzZf/24/ with assumptions.